# Call ruby method inside index.html.erb to load javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to call a ruby method inside index.html.erb that loads all my javascript files? I know you can do that directly using js but I am building a library and I want the client to be able to add the javascript files by simply calling my method.

I guess it will be something like 
    `<%= library.get_javascripts %>`
but I can't figure it out how the code would look like.

Comment: Look into javascript_include_tag

Answer (score 0):

By default, any javascript/css file that you include in your app/assets folder will get loaded through your layout view, and as such, you will have access to those methods within any view in your app/views folder.

If you want to load something specifically, i.e. from the vendor folder you can just use a rails helper `asset_path` like so:

For a css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= asset_path 'my_vendor_css_file.css' %>">
```

For a js file:

```
<script src="<%= asset_path 'my_vendor_js_file.js' %>"></script>
```

Add whichever to your index.html.erb file to load it there.

Comment: And how i would incapsulate that in a method? As i said, i want to simply call the method in index.html.erb and in the method to have something like you said. So <%= library.getJS %> and in a ruby file(inside my library) to have a method called getJS .

Comment: Where are you building your library? If you are building it in the app/assets/javascripts directory you don't have to do anything, it gets included either way, because of the line "<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>" in your application.html.erb file in your layouts folder.

Comment: Otherwise just add this somewhere in your index.html.erb file and the helper will automatically include any new file you create in that directory you specified which holds the library of javascripts: ' javascript_include_tag "/some_directory/my_lib_of_javascripts" '

Comment: To be more explicit: I am building a package for others to use and to be easy to do so. That's why I don't want to put my javascripts in some special place, i just want them to be in my package and to be included from the package by calling my function getJS.

Answer (score 0):

> something like <%= library.get_javascripts %>

Ruby on Rails has [javascript_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag) and [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)